# PHP form-Search script to search text file, find match

Tags: php, forms, full-text-search

I'm very new to PHP and think I'm on the right track with this.

- From my `index.php` form, a user will enter their name, and a number associated to them, both in input boxes.
- They will then select from a drop down list a course they want to take.
- Once they hit the submit button I need to take their name to see if they are already enrolled and if the class is at it's max capacity.
- The student info is in `student.txt` ie `Mike Wazowski:PX-68-524` (student name and number).
- The course info is in `course.txt` ie `Animation Film Design:AFD-250:6` (course name and number and max capacity).
- The search will be in `enrollment.txt` which will hold the course number and the student number.  It will look to see if the student number is already in the file, if not they can enroll if the course is not at it's max capacity.

Thank you.

```html
$datafile = 'enrollment.txt';
// If selection has been made, find a match
 if (isset ($_POST['studentnumber'])) {
    $student = htmlentities ($_POST['studentnumber']);
    $DB = fopen ($datafile, 'r') or die ("$datafile cannot be opened for reading.");
    $found = FALSE;
    while ($record = fgets ($DB) and ! $found) {
       $field = explode (":", htmlentities (trim ($record)));
       $found = $student === $field[1];
    }
    fclose ($DB);
    if ($found) {
       echo "<p>$field[3] $field[1]</p>\n";
    }
 }

$DB = fopen ($enrollfile, 'r') or die ("$enrollfile cannot be opened for reading.");
while ($record = fgets ($DB) ) {
    $field = explode (":", htmlentities (trim ($record)));
    echo "<option value=\"$field[3]\">$field[3] $field[1]</option>\n";
}
fclose ($DB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for the database? It is efficient. While files are slower when your data is large.

Comment: Hi Suraj, at this time I have to use text files.  Using a database will be coming shortly.

Comment: In your php script search for the data from the text files with explode or split functions to recognize data like Roll No, Name, etc... and redirect to page u want to redirect